# Number of solution of an LP with Lagrange

Tags: linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, operations-research

Consider the following problem:

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}f(x)=c^Tx$$
Subject to $ Ax=b$, where $A$ is full rank.
Without any positive requirements (for instance, $x\ge0$), I want to show the following using Lagrange:

- If the problem has a bounded optimal solution, then all the feasible solutions are optimal

I guess the non-negative requirement would give a standard LP. Not having such requirement allows to solve the problem without incurring in infeasability problema due to to the negativity. My idea, up to now, is to use a lagrangian $L(x,\lambda)= c^Tx -\lambda(Ax-b)$ and try to derive some necessary and sufficient conditions for its optimallity.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've seen this post has been marked as low quality. Unfortunately, I can't help you, but can you add more details and your attempt to solve the problem to avoid downvotes and prevent deletion? Good luck and hope you'll find the answer!

Comment: Re VerkhovtsevaKatya's comment, your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You may prove it without using Lagrange, right?